# Word 2010 security warning when opening files from Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-office-2010

My office machine has been replaced as the lease expired, they do that by issuing machines on the current lease, previously used by someone else. So I am on the same Windows 7 64bit Pro, running IE 11 and MS Office 2010. None of that changed.

Previously I was able to click on a Word or Excel document in Sharepoint, and it would open after asking Read Only/Edit. But on the new machine I get a windows credentials prompt (the same as when opening Sharepoint site) and the following "warning" and the document does not open.

[image]

What can be different between the old and new machines which is causing an authentication challenge and the error opening files?

The local admin suggested downloading each and every file, which would be a RPITA.

This only happens to the Office files, PDFs for instance open just fine w/o credentials prompt.

Answer (score 0):

There is [solution](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_integration__sharepoint/2015/04/20/office-2013-error-certificate-error-the-application-experienced-an-internal-error-loading-the-ssl-libraries-when-opening-files/) on Technet. Looks like it describes your situation.

> Windows 7 now has a hotfix and a registry key to allow for TLS 1.1 and
>   TLS 1.2 support for its web service API, this allows Office to be able
>   to access SharePoint on Windows 7 now if the server only supports TLS
>   1.2.
>
> See this KB for more information:
>
> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3140245

Have you tried it?

Comment: That hotfix has been installed before I was issued this machine.

Comment: @ajeh have you read solution? There is some workarounds except one mentioned by me,

Comment: Makes no difference whatsoever